# How to improve this C# Linq code?

Tags: .net, performance, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, c#-4.0

```
customerInfo.Telephone = contactData.Where(d => d.ContactTypeId == (int)ContactType.Phone).FirstOrDefault() != null 
                    ? contactData.Where(d => d.ContactTypeId == (int)ContactType.Phone).FirstOrDefault().Data 
                    : string.Empty;
```

`contactData` is IEnumerator. The problem is with running the same query twice. I could get rid of it if I use a variable, but then there is a new variable to maintain.
Is there a way to make this code more readable and make it run faster without using any other custom libraries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`DefaultIfEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355419%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Try following

```
customerInfo.Telephone = 
    contactData.Where(d => d.ContactTypeId == (int)ContactType.Phone)
      .DefaultIfEmpty(new Contact {Data = ""})
      .First().Data;
```

Comment: Got this exception: `System.NotSupportedException: Unable to create a constant value of type 'Contact'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.`

Comment: This worked for me: `customerInfo.Telephone = contactData.Where(d => d.ContactTypeId == (int)ContactType.Phone1).Select(d=>d.Data)
                    .DefaultIfEmpty(string.Empty)
                    .First();`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
customerInfo.Telephone =
  contactData.Where(d => d.ContactTypeId == (int)ContactType.Phone)
    .Select(d => d.Data)
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? string.Empty;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used your in conjunction with Tilak's

Answer (score 0):

I would use a temporary variable to prevent multiple enumerations:

```
var match = contactData.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ContactTypeId == (int)ContactType.Phone);
customerInfo.Telephone = match == null ? string.Empty : match.Data;
```